# D7 dynamic views by user input

Tags: 7, views, entities

First of all I want to let you know that I am a newbie with Drupal so maybe this question isn't good or even not possible to apply with Drupal.

I got a custom content type that includes in it a lot of fields and among them there are a date field and a list field.

My goal is that a pop window will flow when user enters my site, then he will submit a date and a value that the list contains, and he will get into a page that will display the nodes that include the same input he puts in.

Can someone explain me how to do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a broad question that it pretty much requires some proficiency with several aspects of Drupal.

In short, first I would recommend you that you find a ready [theme](https://drupal.org/project/project_theme) which features some kind of pop-up as you require. Alternatively, you would need to theme a pop-up region [by yourself](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme).

Then, you need [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module with exposed filters [in a block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734145/how-to-put-exposed-filter-in-a-separate-block-in-a-view-in-drupal-7), which you would add to this specific region.